# timestamp of last Monday in C++

Tags: c++, datetime, time

I need to get timestamp (time_t) of the beginning (00:00) of last Monday in my local timezone using C++. Is there any simple way to do it using only standard C++ without using third-party libraries?

Comment: Be careful, talking about C/C++ (i.e. not only one of the two different languages) turns away several usually helpfully minded people here.

Comment: Do you want a `C` or a `C++` solution?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is unclear what exactly you mean by "last Monday".

Comment: @hellow Actually I need C++ solution, but as I understand standard C library is also part of a standard C++ library, so I think C solution is ok too. Or I am not right here?

Comment: That depends on your definition of "simple". I would start with the [tm](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/tm) type. The trickiest part is probably figuring out the date of "last Monday". (And if it *is* Monday, is the "last" one this one or the one a week ago?)

Comment: @melpomene  By "last Monday" I mean first working day of current week. Actually I need to figure out if event that has timestamp happened during this week or not.

Comment: @molbdnilo  If there is not simple solution, complecated solution is ok too. But actually I didn't expected that there is no simple way to do it.

Comment: There is a simple way if you use someone elses library.

Comment: Do you need _monday_ specifically? Or (as you said) the _first working day_? The latter may change depending on the country the user is in. Does the solution need to be cross platform? You might be able to use Windows APIs for localization.

Comment: @Sandro If you actually have a different problem than what you asked about, this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Post a new question about the problem you're really trying to solve instead.

Comment: @IvanRubinson "monday specifically? Or (as you said) the first working day? "  This program is not going to be localized and work in another country. I wrote "first working day" because in some countries week starts from Sunday and somewhere from Monday. I wanted to avoid misunderstanding...

Answer (score 5):

Why no third party libraries? This is much easier with [Howard Hinnant's header only date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) which should be available in a future standard:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    //auto now = sys_days(2018_y/August/12);
    auto now = floor<days>(system_clock::now());
    date::weekday day = weekday{ now };
    now -= day - Monday;
    std::cout << year_month_day(now) << "\n";
    time_t time = now.time_since_epoch().count();
    std::cout << time << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Actually I just didn't want to add add third-party lib in my small program, so I wanted to have only standard libs. But if there is not another simple way, I'll  use this library.

Comment: Always use third party libraries, let someone else do the hard work and fix all the bugs, concentrate on implementing your functionality. Write less code, make fewer mistakes

Comment: Nice answer!  But in the interest of complete transparency, this computes the beginning of the last Monday in UTC, not the computer's local timezone.  For that you need "tz.h".  Convert `system_clock::now()` to a `zoned_time` using `current_zone()` prior flooring to `days`.  Then continue with the same algorithm.  Also if the current day is Monday, and you prefer a week ago, as opposed to the same day, subtract a day from the local `now` prior to starting the algorithm.  It's unclear from the question if this last modification is desired or not.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my own quick solution of this task, I think it can be improved to work with any day of week...

```
time_t get_monday_timestamp(time_t time)                             
{                                                                           
    tm* timeinfo = localtime(&time);                                        
    int wday=timeinfo->tm_wday;                                             
    int hour=timeinfo->tm_hour;                                             
    int min=timeinfo->tm_min;                                               
    int sec=timeinfo->tm_sec;                                               

    time_t SECONDS_IN_DAY = 60 * 60 * 24;                                   

    //monday should be 0 and sunday 6                                       
    wday--;                                                                 
    if(wday == -1)                                                          
    {                                                                       
        wday = 6;                                                           
    }                                                                       

    time -= wday * SECONDS_IN_DAY;                                          
    time -= (sec + 60 * min + 60 * 60 * hour);                              

    return time;                                                            
}
```